# Input string was not in a correct format error.?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, null, int, formatexception

Getting the following error when clicking a link in an application, 'Input string was not in a correct format'.Tried changing things around several times but no luck so this my last resort.

Heres the line of code that brings up the error

Comment: Can you change the complianceaction into string and try out if your query works?

Comment: I changed the complianceaction to string but got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `Request[UrlParameters.UrlParameterName.ComplianceActionRisk]` is not of type int. So, instead of using `Parse`, use `TryParse` which will convert the value to int if its compatible otherwise default value `-1` will be used  -

```
int ComplianceAction = -1;
Int32.TryParse(Request[UrlParameters.UrlParameterName.ComplianceActionRisk],
                       out ComplianceAction);
```